Cheese says "no device found" on Ubuntu24.04LTS
1.The Skype video is working.
2."ffplay /dev/video0" is working.
But when I entered cheese command. Cheese is opening but there is no video. Cheese says "there is no device". Could you please help on this issue?

You don't say if you have snap or apt version installed. I tried it with apt on my rig and it works fine. What happens if you select the video device? Any available? (Preference menu at top of app.)

There is no device in video device menu.

I reinstalled the cheese, now working.

Please post the preceding comment as a self-answer to your own question.

I reinstalled the cheese, now working.
